# How to get Grails app to read config locations from a plugin?

Tags: grails, configuration, grails-plugin

I have a Grails plugin that defines several `grails.config.locations` that should be used when searching for external configuration files.

My Grails (2.3.6) app uses this plugin.

At the top of my app's `Config.groovy` I have:

```
println "Looking for configs at:\n" + grails.config.locations
```

When I do a `grails run-app` I see:

```
Looking for configs at:
[:]
```

How do I get my app to read the config locations that are defined inside the plugins' `Config.groovy`?

Comment: `grails.config.locations` should be present in the `Config.groovy` of the app and should refer the external config files from the plugin. Refer [this for more details](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized).

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro (+1) - a few followup questions: (1) Are you saying that what I'm trying to do is impossible, or just bad practice?

Comment: And (2) what do you mean when you say that `grails.config.locations` should "refer" the external config files *from* the plugin? Can you give an example?

Comment: What you are trying to do is not the way of referring external config. Any external config, for example, `com.example.MyConfig` present in `package com.example` in your plugin then that config file can be used in the app by specifying `grails.config.locations = [com.example.MyConfig]` in the `Config.groovy` of the **app** which uses the plugin instead of specifying in the `Config.groovy` of the plugin. The document mentions exactly about this. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, an app never reads configuration from a plugin. A plugin's config files can only be read by the plugin itself. So you need to move `grails.config.locations` into the `Config.groovy` of the app itself.